# Paypal: How to handle multi-currencies?

Tags: paypal

I written my own shopping cart in PHP. I am using Paypal standard api.

I currently allow the user to change from currencies to use any currency paypal accepts.
My main currency is USD. Now, the confusion I have is understanding about how to process multi-currencies.

I right now have my code that computes the prices based on paypals fees.

For example:

Paypal charges a 3.9% fee for anyone from any other country other then the U.S.

Then there's a fixed fee for the currency used... for USD it's 0.30 each currency has it's own fixed fee. Then there's a 2.5% conversion fee for any currency that needs to be converted.

I can figure out the price to give the customer with the above figures.

Now, I want the customers to be able to pay me in any currency. I need to know what currency they will be paying to give the correct price.

Now, on my own shopping cart system. I give them a drop down menu that they can select which currency to use.

The problem is that I think it is charging the client in that currency.

So, for instance if I charge a customer $200 USD  and when using my cart system. They select HKD.  It will update the price to be $200 HKD  but the problem is that this is totally different... a $200 USD is not the same as $200 HKD in value.

So, the currency value being passed to Paypal API I have no idea what it's for... my guess is that Paypal is giving me the option to grab the currency exchange rates myself and compute the actual value of $200 USD to HKD.

So, here is what I want to do. I want to accept multiple currencies but want to avoid having to deal with currency exchange rates myself.

In my papal account I want to have USD to hold. I might in 5 years decide to hold Euros and HKD's but for now want only USD.

I want to allow customers to pay me in any acceptable currency that paypal accepts.
If I need to compute the price for that currency. I can do it but rather for now want a simple solution.

So, I don't know what I need to pass to the API. I am guessing for now to statically pass the USD as the currency...and guessing that people can pay with another currency on paypals servers.

If I pass in a different currency value like HKD it would turn that $200 USD to a $200 HKD.

I would think I need to pass the price in USD and paypal will convert their currency to USD.

However, if that is the case how would I know what currency the customer is using and what country they reside in?

The reason is that I factor in paypal fees into my prices. So, the currency used and if the user is not in the U.S I factor those fees in... including the conversion fees.

If I send USD currency value... I am sure a person with computer skills could change these values when sent to Paypal. Is there a way to verify that the user is from that country and is using that currency before processing the transaction?

Comment: Make your life easy and leave multi-currency to PayPal: keep your accounts and system in USD or your local currency only. Build in enough margin to cover the fees. Some of this doesn't apply. PayPal charges the customer for currency conversion, not the vendor. Your 2nd-last sentence isn't correct. If you receive money for an incorrect price you can either just return it, or better still keep it: it's a fraud, let them chase you. I strongly suggest you engage a business analyst, rather than trying to design all this yourself if you don't really understand it.

Comment: Ya, I am trying to leave  it to them. I just want to show my USD price and have paypal convert it to another currency that my customer chooses. However, you're wrong about the fees. I get charged 2.9% and .30 for domestic transactions. 3.9% for international customers and a fixed fee based on type of currency used. I tested it via a sandbox and it shows these fees when simulating the transactions. The problem is that I have to 100% rely on my customers to tell me what country and currency they will use. If it's a lie then I get a big surprise from Paypal.

Comment: I'm not seeing that. For example I deal in AUD, just did a sale to Iceland, I received mc_gross=140, mc_fee=5.06, mc_shipping=15.00. This seems normal to me, about 3.6%. It was an e-bay transaction if that makes any difference. Transactions to Germany, Brazil etc show a similar percentage.

Comment: I'm wondering whether you saw those extra charges against the buyer account rather than the seller account?

Comment: No, when I use the sandbox test accounts. I can clearly see using my shopping cart I coded. I changed the info to use the test accounts. I can clearly see the fees. It depends on the conditions. I had it setup to use a business test account that is in the U.S and has U.S dollar.  I  had a buyer test account for both in the U.S with USD and one in Hong Kong with Hong Kong dollar. the 3.9% and conversion fee of 2.5% only applied to the buyer in China. I have the shopping cart to calculate the fees..so if my price is $200 USD it will add in the fees. I will expect $200 in my account.

Comment: ... in my account so what I see currently is when I process a fee it's now showing $200 going into the buy account. Which means the fees I talked about was charged to the account.  The problem is that I don't know how I can  verify the persons country they reside in and the currency they can use.  from my understanding of the fees and based on the sandbox verifying it. I would need to pay 3.9% for international customers and pay a fixed fee for the type of currency they used. For a hKD I will be charged $2.35 plus a 2.5% conversion fee.

Comment: plus a 2.5% conversion fee. For me to avoid the conversion fee... I need to setup my paypal account to hold HKD currency. That way it won't automatically convert.

Comment: Then can someone here explain to me the fees being incurred? I want my website for example lets say for a product I want $200 USD in my pocket. I need to know what Paypal fees I will be charged and I want to show that total to the customer. If they view items on my website. I want them to see $206.50   something like that. That way when they check out on paypal. they will see $206.50. I want to be more direct with my customers on the cost that they will need to pay in order to get that product or service. What would you recommend me to do?